# vb.net on macbook(bootcamp) text is broken

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I installed Windows 10 on my MacBook and installed visual basic
The screen looks like this.
The same thing happens again a few times.

[image: text broken2]

[image: text broken3]

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's a problem with your resolution and/or DPI settings. You're probably using a Retina display with a ginormous resolution and a correspondingly high DPI setting. And while Visual Studio *should* support this, it evidently doesn't. For what it's worth, I gave up on Boot Camp with my MacBook Pro. VirtualBox is so much nicer, and frees from ever having to reboot. The performance difference is negligible, and the driver support is so much better it more than makes up for it.

Comment: Just to add to @CodyGray, I have Windows 10 on a bootcamped Retina MBP, and for the laptop display I have scaling set to 175%, whereas for my 1440p monitors, scaling is set to 100%. The resolutions are set to 2880x1800 for the laptop display, and 2560x1440 for the monitors. **REMEMBER TO LOG OUT AND BACK IN AFTER CHANGING THE DISPLAY SETTINGS**. Hope that helps.